# Evaluation of an integral over the complex unit sphere

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, reference-request

A paper I was reading recently invokes the identity
$$\int_{S^{d-1}_{\mathbb{C}}} \frac{\det A}{\langle Az,z\rangle^d} dz=1$$
where $A$ is a $d \times d$ complex matrix such that $\|A-I\|<1$, $S^{d-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ denotes the complex unit sphere $\{(z_1,\ldots,z_d) \in \mathbb{C}^d \colon \sum_{j=1}^d|z_j|^2=1\}$, and the integral is taken with respect to normalised Lebesgue measure on $S^{d-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$, that is, with respect to the unique Borel probability measure on $S^{d-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ which is invariant under unitary transformations. The identity is not actually derived in the paper, and when I spoke to the authors recently they were not able to remember how the identity was obtained. Is anyone on here able to come up with a proof or a reference?

Note that the condition $\|A-I\|<1$ forces the denominator to be nonzero, since in this case if $\langle Az,z\rangle=0$ and $\|z\|=1$ then $$1=\|z\|^2=|\langle Iz,z\rangle|=|\langle (I-A)z,z\rangle|\leq \|(I-A)z\|.\|z\|\leq \|I-A\|<1,$$
a contradiction. By Schur's triangularisation theorem we can conjugate A by a unitary matrix in order to assume that $A$ is upper triangular, but this has not helped me to significantly reduce the problem. Since the integrand is holomorphic in $A$ and the identity is clearly correct when $A=I$ one might hope to proceed by showing that the integral has zero derivative with respect to $A$, but I have also not succeeded with this approach.

Comment: "The identity is not actually derived in the paper, and when I spoke to the authors recently they were not able to remember how the identity was obtained" Wow (I guess it would be too embarassing to ask the identity of such luminaries...). For a proof, one can assume WLOG that $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: To give the authors their due: there are independent reasons why the result must be true (although it would be hugely circuitous to use those as a method of proving the identity) and one of the authors suggested that by expanding the integrand $(\det A) /(1-\langle (I-A)z,z\rangle)^d$ as a Taylor series it should be possible to obtain the result by turning the crank and grinding through a large family of lesser integrals. It feels like it should have a less dreadful proof than that, though, perhaps using some sort of argument about invariant quantities.